# Using window.print() with React - where to call it whilst avoiding deprecation warning

Tags: reactjs

I am using `window.print()` in a React JS app. I'd like the print modal to fire after data has downloaded, and the content rendered.

In Chrome, I see this warning in the console:

> Invoking 'print()' during microtask execution is deprecated and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5647113010544640 for more details.

Where should I put the call to `window.print` in order to avoid the warning (and eventual deprecation)?

Comment: Can you share something about where you're calling `window.print()` from? Also how are you fetching your data? A synchronous XHR?

Answer (score 3):

It's normal to sow some errors after calling api, I don't know why Chrome team have plan to disallow execute some functions like (alert, print, promt..) during micro task execution. You can work around by putting it in setTimeout function like this:

`setTimeout(function() {
  window.print();
}, 0)`

Comment: @SomethingOn setTimeout will put the function into task queue, not micro-task queue, that's why